# Vue ssr dont gets into the entry-server.js file

Tags: vue.js, es6-promise, server-side-rendering

on an existing express project i am integrating vuejs ssr rendering for vue rendering.

But I did not get my goal because my application never gets into the function exported by entry-server.js and i dont know why.

When I import the bundle of entry-server.js throws me this error:

```
module.exports = createRouter;
           ^
```

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'
    at Object. (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:7850:16)
    at Object. (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:7851:30)
    at **webpack_require** (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:21:30)
    at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:7751:20)
    at **webpack_require** (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:21:30)
    at Object.module.exports.**webpack_exports**.a (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:7723:74)
    at **webpack_require** (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:21:30)
    at module.exports.module.exports.rawScriptExports (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:64:18)
    at Object. (/home/raul/Documentos/Workshop/vuejs website template/vuessr-bundle.js:67:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)

Please, help

Comment: Try to replace `module.exports = createRouter` with `export default createRouter`.

Comment: I start again the project xd, is personal so nothing happens...